# Matlab - Scatter plot multiple classess with different colors

Tags: matlab, visualization

Let's say I have a I have a *1000x2* dataset and its corresponding *1000x1* labels.

We can seperate the data into 10 classes (The labels array has 10 unique values range from 1 to 10).

What is the shortest way to visualize these 10 classes with 10 different colors in Matlab?

I am currently doing it manually with just two classes like this:

```
class_1 = data(labels == 1,:);
class_2 = data(labels == 2,:);
plot(class_1(:,1),class_1(:,2),'*');
hold on;
plot(class_2(:,1),class_2(:,2),'o');
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest is to use the [`gscatter`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html) function from the stats toolbox (if you have it) which does exactly what you want out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not define a color for each class MATLAB will automatically change color for each new plot but by default there are only 7 colors defined so for your case with 10 plots some classes will have the same color.

One way to solve it would be to define your colors and markers in a cell array and then do the plotting in a loop. Here is your example with `class_1` being blue stars and `class_2` green circles:

```
classes = {class_1, class_2};
my_colors = {[0 0 1], [0 1 0]}; 
my_markers = {'*','o'};
figure(1), hold on
for i=1:length(classes)
    plot(classes{i}(:,1),classes{i}(:,2),'Color', my_colors{i}, 'Marker', my_markers{i});
end
```

This could easily be extended to all include all 10 classes and you can easily change color and marker for each class.

Another thing you can do is to change the default number of colors that MATLAB has and you can also change what the default colors are if you don't like them. You can read about it here: [Why Are Plot Lines Different Colors?](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-plot-lines-different-colors.html)

Comment: An alternative would be to use RGB triplets to make colours; you can create (almost) any colour that way.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the colourmap used (of the inbuilt ones 'jet' is probably best for this purpose but you can also [create your own](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)), you can simply use your `labels` vector as the color input into the [`scatter`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) function. This will automatically map the range of values in that vector to the entire colormap used.

`scatter(data(:,1),data(:,2),[],labels)`

(change `[]` to a number if you want to change from the default marker size)